# I have a little wrong in my Flutter code while i'm trying to display datas from MYSQL database on List View

Tags: php, flutter, dart

I'm trying to display the datas from MySql database. But i got 2 errors.

1st error: **The property 'length' can't be unconditionally accessed because the receiver can be 'null'.**

2nd error: **A value of type 'Object?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List'.**

this is my code part where the error occurs

```
return snapshot.hasData ? ListView.builder(
            itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
              itemBuilder: (context,index)
              {
               List list = snapshot.data ;
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text(list[index]['Name']),
                );
              }
          ) : Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
```

i got 1st error on `itemCount: snapshot.data.length,`
2nd error on `List list = snapshot.data ;`

Other side php code all are done. I got error only this. I don't know why.

if anyone know please tell me the reason.
this is my flutter full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
//import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:async';
//import 'package:path/path.dart' as Path;

void main()
{
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Home(),
    );
  }
}

Future getData() async{
  var url = 'http://192.168.8.188/ziga/CRUD flat/index.php';
  final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
  var dataReceived = response.body;
  return dataReceived;

}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("XAMPP to Flat"),
      ),
      body: new FutureBuilder(
        future: getData(),
         builder: (context,snapshot){
          if(snapshot.hasError)
            {
              print(snapshot.error);
            }
          return snapshot.hasData ? ListView.builder(
            itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
              itemBuilder: (context,index)
              {
               List list = snapshot.data ;
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text(list[index]['Name']),
                );
              }
          ) : Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
         }
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here in this method.

```
Future getData() async{
  var url = 'http://192.168.8.188/ziga/CRUD flat/index.php';
  final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
  var dataReceived = response.body;
  return dataReceived;
}
```

Here dart cannot recognize the response type that you are expecting to be a list. Also its not always guaranteed, the API call will responds you the success. So You need to wrap the api call on `try catch` block, Also you need to try to cast the `response.body` to `List<Map<String, dynamic>>`.